# How does loading of javascript work with Rails + Sprockets + jQuery + Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I don't get it. I have a Rails app with a little Javascript. I still don't understand how the pieces of the tech stack I use work in isolation and together.

These were two of my problems:

1. requesting a Rails action rendering a .js-template resulted in double rendering of a form for example
2. either bootstrap js didn't work or jQuery was not found depending on load order of require statements in application.js

I know from research and trial and error that

1. has to do with loading js-files more than needed (exactly once) and
2. seems to have to do with require-alternative or load-order. Yet I don't exactly know which part I have to understand: Is it Javascript or Rails or Sprockets or jQuery or Bootstrap or a combination ororor.

What seems to work for my app right now is the following application.js.coffee

```
@import bootstrap
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require_tree .
```

1. having @import bootstrap instead of #= require bootstrap first solves the double render issue
2. importing bootstrap first and not third as I had it before solves the bootstrap-dropdown issue

I didn't find a tutorial/resource yet where this explained for somebody who doesn't understand it yet.

Any explanation or hint or tutorial/resource would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help: [Manifest files and directives - RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) and this [video about the asset pipeline](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYdBpNUVxuI).

I also would use `application.js` without coffescript. You shouldn't write javascript code in this file.

The order of the requires is important. Things on top get loaded first into the browser.